# Automatically refresh a list of IP Addresses connected in Java

Tags: java, networking, ip

I'm writing some code that sends/receives information from computers connected to the same network. I have a method that gets the IP of the online computers at that exact moment, but I need to refresh the list when a new IP appears/disappears.

I don't think having a thread and `while (true)` calling the method is the best solution. And I can't think of anything else - any suggestions?

Here is the sample of the code I use to search for active computers on the network:

```
public List<String> searchApps() {
    List<AddressServiceTypePair> ip = this.networkController.getDiscovered();  //returns an ArrayList<AddressServiceTypePair>

    onlineApps.clear();
    for (AddressServiceTypePair service : ip) {
        onlineApps.add(service);
    }

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (AddressServiceTypePair aux : onlineApps) {
        list.add(aux.getIP());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You can poll yourself or maybe add a listener somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to generalize based on the unclear code sample posted. However, I'm assuming you are writing some type of client and server code. There is no simple way to be notified of an added/removed computer on the network. I would be surprised if you needed an up-to-the-*moment* list of IPs. You could put your IP-discovering method in an infinite loop and simply include `Thread.sleep(milliseconds);` in your loop.

If you really do need extremely up-to-date information, you could have each connected computer also connect to a Socket on another port in a separate thread, then try to read from the Socket - that way you get an Exception as soon as the Socket closes. You can add the IP of the client when the Socket is created, and your catch block can then update your list of active IPs when the Socket closes, signaling that client is no longer connected.

Comment: I guess you are right! I will just put the ip disconvering in a loop true with Thread.sleep(1000) - (Maybe not 1000 ) .... 1 second its enough, no one notes it the difference. I just need to pay attention to the performance

Comment: Just one more thing if i have to put the list of ip in a jlist i need to create another thread with the same time sleep as the thread to search the IP to display on the jlist with for... right?

Comment: I would simply update the JList as part of the same while loop.